# CUSPARSE internal format conversion in csrmv/csrmm

Tags: cuda

I’m using CUSPARSE functions to perform sparse matrix-vector/matrix-matrix multiplications.

Sparse matrices are stored in CSR format. While profiling the app under Visual Profiler, I’ve noticed that for each call to cusparse(S/D)csrmv or cusparse(S/D)csrmm there is a memory allocation/memset/copy.

By looking at kernel names in the profiler, it looks like CUSPARSE converts matrix from CSR format to HYB format on each call which is a waste of time in my case as I could create matrix in the right format before launching computations.

While CUSPARSE has HYB version of matrix-vector multiplication (hybmv), it does not have a corresponding version for matrix-matrix multiplications, looks like only CSR format is supported.

Is it possible to avoid matrix conversions when doing matrix-matrix muls in CUSPARSE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked around about this.  The answer I received is that cusparse does not convert from CSR to HYB format when executing a `csrmv` operation.  The hyb you are seeing is probably within a mangled form of an internal kernel name something like this:

```
_Z14csrMm_hyb_coreIdLi7ELi6ELi2ELi1ELb0EEv19cusparseCsrMmParamsIT_Ei
```

This is a cusparse internal kernel which has hyb in it's name, but it is not connected to the HYB format.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to avoid these allocations/copies at all?

Comment: I'm not able to provide much additional information.  I think you should assume that the libraries were written by GPU coding experts who are not going to do things that are obviously wasteful or inefficient.  In all probability the allocations you are witnessing are necessary temporary allocations required for the function processing.  It might be nice to have a permanently allocated scratch space for repeated calls, but unfortunately the library doesn't offer that level of abstraction, and it's uncertain what the benefit would be.  In short, there is no way to affect this low-level behavior.